# ruby lambda capture : a weird effect and workaround

Tags: ruby, lambda, closures, capture

```
closures = []
vals = ('a'..'z').to_a
until vals.empty?
 val = vals.shift()
 closures << lambda { puts val }
end
closures.each { |l| l.call() }
```

this Ruby code prints 'z' for every call which is a bit surprising

```
def closure(val)
 lambda {puts val}
end

closures = []
vals = ('a'..'z').to_a
until vals.empty?
 val = vals.shift()
 closures << closure(val)
end
closures.each { |l| l.call() }
```

this prints 'a' to 'z' as it would be expected.

so what I see here is certain misbehavior in Ruby lambdas capturing their parameters at the moment of their creation
can please anyone explain this effect by citing Ruby specification ? (my Ruby is 2.2.5p319/Cygwin)
should this be reported as a bug in Ruby bug tracker ?
or it is an expected behavior ?
or it has already been fixed in some further version of Ruby ?

thanks in advance for your replies

UPDATE. Here is the same code ported to Perl. Surprisingly, but it works as expected:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @vals = 'a'..'z';
my @subs = (); 

while (@vals) { 
    my $val = shift @vals; 
    push @subs, sub { print "$val\n"; }; 
} 

$_->() for @subs;
```

Comment: The same thing happens in JavaScript for the same reasons, it is just a matter of when `val` is evaluated. Try `v = 6; f = -> { puts v }; f.call; v = 11; f.call` for another illustration.

Comment: `val` is a reference, closures do remember  the  scope they are in but  do not create snapshots of it. It would be a bad idea memory wise

Comment: in Perl :

`    use strict;
    use warnings;

    my @vals = 'a'..'z';
    my @subs = ();

    while (@vals) {
     my $val = shift @vals;
     push @subs, sub { print "$val\n"; };
    }
    $_->() for @subs; `

prints from 'a' to 'z' as it would be expected<br>
how could this be explained ?

Comment: finally made this work by using loop : `
    closures = [] ;
    vals = ('a'..'z').to_a ;
    loop do
     break if vals.empty? ;
     val = vals.shift() ;
     closures << lambda { puts val }
    end ;
    closures.each { |l| l.call() } `

Comment: That's so weird :)

Answer (score 2):

Variables are captured by reference in Ruby, not by value (the same thing is true in Python, JavaScript, and many other languages). Furthermore, the scope of `val` is the function scope, not scoped to the inside of the loop, so you don't get a new variable `val` in each iteration of the loop -- it's the same variable `val`; you are just assigning another value to it in each iteration.

In each iteration of the loop, a closure is created that references the variable `val` -- the exact same variable `val`. Thus, when the closures are evaluated later, they all read the same value -- the value of the (single) variable `val` at that point.

When you pass it to a method and create the closure inside the method, it's different because the variable that the closure captures is the `val` in the body of the method `closure`, scoped to that method. Each time you call the method `closure`, you get a new variable `val`, whose value is the value passed in, and it is never altered thereafter (nothing in `closure` assigns to it). So when the value is read by the closure later, it is still the value passed in to the call of `closure` when the closure was created.

Answer (score 1):

I believe what is happening here is in the first case

```
closures = []
vals = ('a'..'z').to_a
until vals.empty?
 val = vals.shift()
 closures << lambda { puts val }
end
closures.each { |l| l.call() }
```

Every time you push `lambda { puts val }` into `closures`, you are simply pushing in a method that does not remember the current value of `val`. So, if we add the line `puts val` at the end of the `until` loop, `val = 'z'`, so when you call each lambda in the closure, you are calling `puts val`, with the current value of `val`.

In the second case,

```
def closure(val)
 lambda {puts val}
end

closures = []
vals = ('a'..'z').to_a
until vals.empty?
 val = vals.shift()
 closures << closure(val)
end
closures.each { |l| l.call() }
```

When you push `closure(val)` into closures, ruby is able to remember the current value of the argument, so you are pushing `closure('a')`, `closure('b')`, etc. Now, when you call each `l` in `closures`, you are able to print out a to z.